# How can I embed a PNG image in a stack (mustache) template?

Tags: haskell, mustache, haskell-stack

My specific problem is that I want to create a [stack template](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates) to replace the `hakyll-init` executable that is included in the [hakyll](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.9.5.1) package.

The problematic file is [haskell-logo.png](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/blob/ba272c9ba9cddb306cd30c976fb95a8ae7a06b85/data/example/images/haskell-logo.png). How do I have to encode this file so it is recreated when I run `stack new my-project my-template.hsfiles`?

Comment: [Googling](https://www.google.de/search?q=mustache+template+%22binary%22+file) reveals that there is [at least one mustache implementation that doesn't support binary files](https://github.com/tests-always-included/mo#general-scripting-issues). It does not reveal however if mustache in general doesn't allow embedding binary files.

Comment: Isn't there [a way](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates/blob/master/yesod-postgres.hsfiles#L8269) in [the link](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates) you found?

Comment: @jeiea Cheers! I hadn't seen that bit before and didn't realize that I could specify an encoding like in `{-# START_FILE BASE64 img.png #-}`.

Comment: Yeah then I'll add it as answer for completeness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify base64 as content encoding like [this](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates/blob/master/yesod-postgres.hsfiles#L8269).

```
{-# START_FILE BASE64 static/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot #-}
b08AABFOAAACAAIABAAAAAAABQAAAAAAAAABAJABAAAEAExQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAA
```

That feature is provided from this [stack's dependency](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/project-template), although not directly documented.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally discouraged here on SO. You can keep the link as suggested further reading, but please include the relevant information directly in your answer.